# How to use es6 object.assign and find methods in typescript file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

My project migrate java script to typescript, I can't use object.assign() and find methods,

Comment: why can't you use `Object.assign` anymore?

Comment: There's no fundamental reason you can't use `Object.assign` (though you probably need to do some checks first to ensure type safety) and `find` (assuming you mean array's `find`) in TypeScript. What specific problem are you having, with what code, and what research have you done into the errors (or whatever) you're getting?

Comment: Try this to convert js to typescript http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Comment: 1)
 // Merge an object
let first = {name: 'Tony'};
let last = {lastName: 'Stark'};
let person = Object.assign(first, last);

i am trying to use the above code in typescript
but i am getting this error
error:Property 'assign' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.

 2)
 //find object in array
  var array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];

    var found = array1.find(function (element:any) {
        return element > 10;
    });
 i am trying to use the above code in typescript
but i am getting this error
 error: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'number[]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the contents of your `tsconfig.json` file - there is a field under `compilerOptions` called `lib`, which is an array of strings.  The `find` method on an Array in JavaScript is an ES6 method, so you need to make sure that `es6` is listed in that `lib` array:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6"]
  }
}
```